# No method setRootLevel() in log4j class configurator

Tags: java, log4j2

When I am using

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
```

there is no method setRootLevel() available.

[image]

I am using the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Maybe someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really say why you aren't seeing all the methods but they are there. This is what I see in IntelliJ. The setRootLevel method was added in the 2.4 release. I suppose if you have 2.3 on your class path somehow that could be causing the problem.

[image: Configurator in IntelliJ]